# Distinct Users Filtering

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a messaging App in django but I couldn't re-order the Users properly

Here's the Models,

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender")
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="receiver")
    msg_content = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here's the View,

```
def message(request):
    users = Message.objects.filter(Q(sender=request.user) | Q(receiver=request.user)).values('sender__first_name', 'receiver__first_name', 'receiver__id', 'sender__id').annotate(Max('id')).order_by('-id__max')
    return render(request, 'chat/users.html', {'users': users})
```

Here's what I tried in Template,

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% if user.sender__id != request.user.id %}
        {{ user.sender__first_name }}
    {% else %}
        {{ user.receiver__first_name }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This code seems working fine but it's returning same user "Twice" as long as request.user send someone a message & that person replies back to it.

How can I fix this problem? Thank You . . .

Comment: Have you tried inserting [`distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) into your query?

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes I tried but it returned an eeor saying distinct() don't work with annotate.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query:

```
def message(request):
    users = Message.objects.filter(Q(sender=request.user) | Q(receiver=request.user)).values('sender__first_name', 'receiver__first_name', 'receiver__id', 'sender__id').annotate(Max('id', distinct = True)).order_by('-id__max')
return render(request, 'chat/users.html', {'users': users})
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Sir, it will give an error that distinct don't work with annotate.

Comment: Updated the answer. Can you check now

Comment: Sir, it's returning an error, "'bool' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression'"

Comment: Count takes an argument like this: `Count('id', distinct=True)`. Can you try the same with Max like `Max('id',  distinct = True)`. I am not sure but you can check.